# Need assistance regarding iOS Background Execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, background-task

My `ViewController` which is presented modally have a save button which save the data in database and then `unwind` the `ViewController`.

I am also posting a `notification` from `applicationDidEnterBackground` to call the `save method` so when if user did not tap the save button and and hit the `iPhone home button` user data gat saved.

Just Like Apple [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) suggests

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

**Question 1:**
My task is not that long it will take few seconds to save few hundred rows in `DB`, is it still necessary to put inside `dispatch_async`?

**Question 2:**
User can tap save button and immediately hit the iPhone home button in this case my save method will be called twice and it will be bad for my app, should I use `dispatch_once` or is there any other way?

**Question 3**
Apple Doc says:

> Failure to call the endBackgroundTask: method for a background task
>   will result in the termination of your app. If you provided an
>   expiration handler when starting the task, the system calls that
>   handler and gives you one last chance to end the task and avoid
>   termination.

1. If my app is running and `endBackgroundTask:` is not called will iOS crash the app?
2. What `avoid termination` means, if my app is in background and my task is also finished still iOS will keep my app alive and will prevent from terminating it?

**Question 4**
For how long my app will remain functional after going into background while using this `backgroudtask`? because Apple mention in comments `// Start the long-running task and return immediately.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

If your operation takes less than 5 seconds (according to [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:%20Documentation)), you can do it without `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` and `dispatch_async`, but you have to consider if that data is going to increase with time, if that's the case then you're better off doing it with `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` and `dispatch_async`.

**Question 2**

What I would do, is store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` about the save operation, so in case the save operation is still underway you can avoid trying to save it again.

**Question 3**

1.- As stated, your app will be terminated and purged from memory because you're still holding onto resources when you don't need it anymore.

2.- Normally when the user leaves your app, your app can still run some operations in the background from time to time or in response to a push notification if you have that mode enabled. But if your app is terminated by either the user or the OS then you won't be able to

**Question 4**

Sadly there's no specification about it in the documentation, but you can rest assured it's more than 5 seconds if you use `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`.

Hope this clears any doubts.

Cheers

**-----EDIT 1-----**

As stated by @Paulw11, For **Question 4**, "it is currently 3 minutes and you can examine the UIApplication property backgroundTimeRemaining to determine how much time is left."

Comment: For question 4 there is an answer as to how long a task can execute; it is currently 3 minutes and you can examine the UIApplication property `backgroundTimeRemaining` to determine how much time is left. It is true, however that how long your app will remain idle in the background (such that tapping the icon restores it rather than launches a new copy) isn't known because this depends on what else the user does in the device, available memory and so on

Comment: @GianniCarlo Thank you so much for the detail answer, Please tell me one more thing if user double tap the home button and terminate the app, will baskgroundtask still work the same way.

Comment: @S.J nope, once the app was force killed by the user in that manner or killed by the OS, no background tasks will be able to run until your app is opened by the user again. There's an exception to this rule, and that is in response to a special kind of push notification used by apps that do voice communication like the call in whatsapp, with that push the app will be raised from the dead in background. I wouldn't recommend using that type of push if your app doesn't do voice communication or related, you can risk being rejected when submitting to the appstore.